# How to set a multiple DIVs with pictures side by side to each other?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to set multiple divs side-by-side that are centered and have at least 10 pixels gap between each other? I managed to do it but the following divs went right under the first 2.

Here is an example of what outcome I am expecting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9jNd.jpg

And here is the outcome I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ipn.jpg

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(50px, 20px);
}

.column1 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex element in your css:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but is there anyway to make it smaller and centered?

Comment: add justify-content:center; and set a width

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to place them side by side. If you want them to fill the width of your parent element, use min-width on the children calculate 100% by the amount of divs and subtract the column gap. `min-width: calc(100% / var(--num-cols) - var(--col-gap));` i used css variables.

```css
:root {
  --num-cols: 4;
  --col-gap: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* centers content when flex axis is set as row */
  justify-content: center;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* will fill parents width with children including gap
  /* can also use flex-grow: 1; to fill parents width with children */ 
  /* min-width: calc(100% / var(--num-cols) - var(--col-gap)); */
  flex-grow: 1; /* remove if you do not want to spread entire width of parent width */
}

.column1~.column1 {
  /* adds a gap of 10px to all but first col element */
  margin-left: var(--col-gap);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column1">
    <img src="profilepiclink256x" style="width:50%">
    <h1>text name</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```